# How to get last/Bottom row of the table in Sqlite via Sql Query

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

I am trying to fetch the last row of my sqlite3 db.
can anybody tell me the query syntax.

Comment: i tried select  chat from Mytable where touser="nitesh"  order by timestamp desc Limit 1;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT field
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY field DESC
LIMIT 1
```

assuming that ordering by `DESC` puts your last row *first*

Comment: yep i tried the same but now my ordering it on primary key so its works just fine. thanks a lot for your help